# Каламбур, тамбур — этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "каламбур" и "тамбур" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

[**та́мбур**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=upo6cH_92xcC&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=CDAo-xYRnO&sig=ACfU3U2oLfu0o3dJ8oF7SKtk4576Tfdy6g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs1K3clonhAhVqposKHQrrClQQ6AEwCXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&f=false)
Пристройка к зданиям и сооружениям перед наружными дверями или проходное пространство за ними, служащее для защиты от холода и непогоды;
закрытая площадка в торце железнодорожного вагона;
в архитектуре ― барабан купола, то есть опирающаяся на своды цилиндрическая или многогранная часть здания (обычно с окнами), служащая основанием купола;
род вязания или вышивки, при котором петля заходит за петлю.
Фр. *tambour* ― барабан < перс. *tabir* ― литавры.

В этимологическом словаре М. Фасмера:
**та́мбур**
(в разных знач.), та́мбурный (напр., шов), прилаг. Из франц. *tambour* "барабан, тамбур для вышивания", ст.-франц. *tabour*, которое производили из араб. (Литтман 90 и сл.; Гамильшег, ЕW 827; М.-Любке 701; Локоч 159).
[Из арабского ― طنبور *tunbūr* ― барабан, цилиндр.]

Версий происхождения слова [**каламбу́р**](https://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/Kalambur-946%20(1).html) предостаточно.
**1.** (*Calambour, Calembourg*) — французское название игры слов, одинаково пишущихся или произносимых. Родоначальником К. одни называют графа Каланбера или Калемберга (*Calember*) из Вестфалии, жившего при Людовике XIV в Паре или при дворе Станислава Лещинского в Лешевилле, другие — аптекаря Каланбура в Париже. В конце XVIII стол. слово К. приобрело уже право гражданства. Ф. Шаль и после него Литтре выводят слово К. из появившегося около 1500 г. сборника шуток: "Der Pfaffe von Kahlenberg" (Брокгауз и Ефрон).
**2.** (*calembour*) ― происхождение слова К. не выяснено. Существует лишь ряд анекдотов, связывающих это слово то с названием города Калемберга (в котором будто бы жил во времена Лютера немецкий пастор Вейганд фон Тебен, славившийся шутками), то с различными анекдотическими личностями. Существует еще предположение, что слово К. произошло от итальянского выражения «calamo burlare» ― шутить пером (Литературная энциклопедия).
**3.** "Игра слов", через франц. *calembour*, происхождение которого, объясняемое из анекдота о попе из Каленберга (см. Клюге-Гётце 275; Брюкнер 213) романисты оспаривают (М. Фасмер).

Со словом *тамбур* ни одна из этих версий никаким образом не пересекается (ни со значением, ни с происхождением) ― слова не являются этимологически однокоренными.